# Adverbial form of "scrutiny"

Tags: adverbs, word-formation

What is the adverbial form of the word *scrutiny*? I'm looking for the exact synonym of the "with scrutiny" expression. I've tried searching for the form like *scrutinily* but I've only found something like *scrutinizingly*. Does *scrutinizingly* have the meaning of "with scrutiny"?

The context is that I am trying to describe an act of watching some tv series for my thesis - I had to watch it really carefully in an analytical way and stop the recording every minute or so to write down the sentences I've just heard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in practice, most people would simply use the verb 'scrutinize' instead of saying 'watch with scrutiny', which accordingly doesn't sound very idiomatic to me.

That being said, ['scrutinizingly' does exist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scrutinizingly?r=66); it means 'in a scrutinizing manner'.

You could say of your research, "In the course of my analysis, I had to carefully scrutinize the TV series and transcribe the dialogue".